# expected something between the beginning of the request and select (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to run this simple query:

select * from table;

but I get this error: expected something between the beginning of the request and select..

Please how do I solve this?

Comment: Do you have multiple queries in the same tab?

Comment: Hey @Andrew no I don't

Comment: Perhaps there are some non-display characters prior to the S in select?